# Distributed nature of diaspora*

Tags: diaspora

So diaspora* is distributed in nature with various "seed" servers (from what I understand, similar to IRC node servers).

Will all users in all the various seed servers be connectable to all other users on the other seeds?

If so, how is this intended to be achieved? How do you keep track of which user is on which seed and make the right connection? And how would search work across the seeds?

Comment: I think it's more similar to XMPP. In IRC, users from one network cannot contact users in other networks.

Comment: I expect it will follow a model similar to http://status.net

Answer (score 1):

According to what I can gather from the mailing list, to add a friend from another seed you need to add the seed's address, as in 'user@server.com'

In the future, the goal would be to implement:

- Web services interface to enable seed to seed communication (federation)
- DHT (distributed hash table), to enable seeds to share their list of known seeds with each other, so a new seed would only need to add a couple of other existing seeds to receive new entries for its list.

https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/wiki/Roadmap

http://groups.google.com/group/diaspora-dev/browse_thread/thread/ea077ec422728cfc/7b3295b3d59c3d72?lnk=gst&q=search#